# CSS Background over container

Tags: html, css

Let's assume I've a got wrapper which is `996px` wide and is centered on the page.

```
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 996px;
}
```

I now have some elements like header, navi, ... . 
Now I want to create a colored "field/banner" which is `30%` of this wrapper and is align right (till here no problem)

```
.field {
    background-color: #000;
    width:30%;
    height:125px;
    float:right;
}
```

This is working in my sample. (Example width adjusted widths: http://jsfiddle.net/8Lvh20qs/)

Now I want that the background of the field goes till the end of the desktop (right), but the text is only inside the container. How I can solve this issues?

example: [image: It should look like this]

Comment: you will need a wrapper for this so field is inside wrapper and wrapper extends all the way to desktop container. else if text is single line having `.field` `width:100%` and `text-aling:right` will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding another container with `position: absolute;` Please also pay attention to the added property `position: relative`to `.container` otherwise `position: absolute` inside this container will not work

**//EDITED**

should now look like your image. 
attention: you need to prefix the *transform: translate* property i added for other browsers than chrome. it translates -50% of it's own height up - which leads to the container being always centered inside the container.

```css
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 316px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
}
.field {
    background-color: #000;
    color:#fff;
    width:30%;
    height:50px;
    padding-right: 100%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 70%;
  
}
.placeholder {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="field">text inside container</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think the OP wants the black containing element to extend outside of the container to the edge of the desktop

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've added an example picture in my question. sorry if it was not clear described

Comment: ah ok xD you want it vertically to fit until the end of the screen xD edited the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE this answer was posted before latest OP edit, it solves the issue shown in  image below**

[image]

You will need a wrapper for this so field is inside wrapper and wrapper extends all the way to desktop container. Else if text is single line having `.field` `width:100%` and `text-align:right;` will solve the issue.

This is the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lvh20qs/12/) (with wrapper)

css:

```
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 316px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 600px;
}
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}

.field {
    position:relative;
    background-color: inherit;
    color:#fff;
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
}
.placeholder {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="field">text inside container</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the background of the field goes till the end of the container you have to assign a height of 100% to the `.field` and `overflow:hidden` to `.container` (so the div does not come out from the container).

```css
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 316px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.field {
    background-color: #000;
    color:#fff;
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
}
.placeholder {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="field">text inside container</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

when you use floats it removes the item from it's containing element. Try `width: 30% margin-left: 70%`.

Comment: I've just wrote a small sample. thats not the real code. but thats not the problem :)

Comment: @DanP. okay i'm still not 100% sure what you mean but this is what i've came up with. http://codepen.io/mike-grifin/pen/waBQZM